# Can I have different audio come out of my computer and monitor?

Tags: mac, audio, hdmi, vga

I previously had my monitor set up through a VGA cable and I was able to play music through an audio jack on my monitor — All while listening to something else through my headphones plugged into my computer. Now that I switched from VGA to HDMI, it doesn't seem to do the same thing.

Is this possible with an HDMI cable? Or is this only a VGA thing?

Comment: When you say "listening to something else" what was the source of that "something else?"  Was it the computer or another audio source?

Answer (score 1):

HDMI (unlike VGA) combines audio and visual in a single cable — VGA just does visual.

Your monitor was using the audio jack as an **input**, and playing sound from the source connected there (music player, etc.). Your computer was using its audio jack as an **output**, playing music to your headphones.

Now that you have an HDMI cable, your monitor most likely uses its audio jack as **output**, because it already has an input for sound — the HDMI cable. My guess would be that if you plugged in headphones to your monitor, you would hear the sound coming from your computer.

There is a way to have the monitor **and** computer speakers play the same output (Audio MIDI Setup), but I don't think you have have two different outputs.